# Fixed filter bar in mat select in angular 9

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm using angular 8 and I implement the filter in dropdown fields. But I don't know how can I fix the search bar at the top of the mat select.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-2ngntr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

**html**

```
<h4>mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
     <input (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)"> // **Send user input to TS**
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of selectedStates" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**ts**

```
states: string[] = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
    'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
    'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
    'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
  ];


selectedStates = this.states; 


onKey(value) { 
this.selectedStates = this.search(value);
}


search(value: string) { 
  let filter = value.toLowerCase();
  return this.states.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter));
}
```

Comment: Can you add it to stackblitz?

Comment: @JanithaRasanga yes,ofcourse [link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-2ngntr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ngx-mat-select-search package to achieve the same:

First Install:

```
npm install ngx-mat-select-search
```

In app.module.ts:

```
import { NgxMatSelectSearchModule } from 'ngx-mat-select-search';
and in imports array:

imports: [
   ....,
   NgxMatSelectSearchModule 
]
```

HTML Code:

```
<mat-select [formControl]="control" ngDefaultControl placeholder="Tags" #Select>
        <ngx-mat-select-search [placeholderLabel]="'Search Item'" [noEntriesFoundLabel]="'No matching records found'" [formControl]="control"
         ngDefaultControl></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option class="m-t" *ngFor="let obj of filteredRecords | async" [value]="obj">
            {{obj}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

[CheckThisSample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-search-uyecug)